# How to programmatically custom form field?

Tags: 8, forms

I want to display a form textfield with this HTML output:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="" class="">Amount (in dollars)</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="">
          <div class="input-group-addon">€ / month</div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

I try this in my custom form :

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $fields = [
        'field_1',
        'field_2',
        'field_3',
    ];

    foreach ($fields as $field) {

        $form[$field] = array(
            '#type'             => 'textfield',
            '#prefix'           => '<label>My label</label>',
            '#size'             => 30,
            '#default_value'    => 0,
            '#required'         => TRUE,
            '#suffix'     => '<div class="input-group-addon">€ / mois</div>',
            '#attributes' => array('class' => array('form-control text-right')),
        );
    }

    return $form;
}
```

And HTML output result look like :[image]

Comment: You'll probably have to create your own custom Element to achieve the goal. Normally in this cases you better workout on your CSS if you're trying to change the markup to fit some CSS in.